# Best name to name a table

Tags: naming-convention

The project I am currently working request me to name the tables to something like: `df_cmn_aum_xx_typ_cur` instead of something like `courses`.

Are there some known standards or best practices to recommend my bosses to abandon this convention?

Comment: Naming things is notoriously hard. It's too subjective to get a once-and-for-all answer, but there are a lot of good points here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions

Comment: I think `F9018` is a much better name than either of your options.

Comment: hehe.... I think the same, honestly

Answer (score 2):

Always name your table and column with meaningful words.  Abbreviations are subjective. It may save few bites but very difficult to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

Started as a comment and got to long.

At first glance and with no idea why the current names are in use.  I don't see anything wrong with `df_cmn_aum_xx_typ_cur` I would assume that at some point, multiple similar tables are queried and/or migrated together.

Before you try and change the current convention, maybe find out why it was created?

Comment: Well... their reasons are that the names are consistent among other applications. For instance "df" means "definition". "cmn" means "common" and so on. So, the point is I found very difficult to memorize that and I don't understand why, if the entity is used to store course information, don't just name it "courses"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593582/database-naming-conventions-by-microsoft).

Avoid spaces and punctuation in the object name.  For example dbo.[table name]  or dbo.[table.name]